# What does "overhead" memory refer to in the case of Linked Lists?

Tags: python, memory-management, linked-list

I understand that a node is usually 8 bytes, 4 for a value, 4 for a pointer in a singly linked list.

Does this mean that a doubly linked list node is 12 bytes in memory with two pointers?

Also this book I'm reading talks about how theres 8 bytes of "overhead" for every 12 byte node, what does this refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're evidently talking about a 32-bit machine since your pointers and values are 4 bytes.  Obviously, that's different for a 64-bit machine.

Second, the value needn't be 4 bytes.  Frequently the value is a pointer or an int, in which case it is 4 bytes (on your 32-bit machine).  But if it was a double, for example, it would be 8 bytes.  In fact, the payload could be any type at all, and have that type's size.

Third, your book probably is referring to the two pointers - the links - as the "overhead'.

Fourth, your book is omitting the impact of the memory manager ("heap manager").  Frequently, because of alignment issues and heap management issues, heap elements are larger than actually requested.  Most heap implementations on a 32-bit machine won't allocate 12 bytes when you ask for 12.  They'll allocate 16 bytes. (The last 4 bytes are not used by your program.)  Because for many machines, 8-byte alignment of certain values (e.g., doubles) is either required by the machine architecture or desirable for performance reasons. You have to investigate yourself, for your particular heap implementation (that is, the compiler's run-time's heap implementation) what kind of overhead it imposes.  Additionally, some heap implementations (many?) actually use memory inside the allocated object for its own bookkeeping purposes.  In this case, that header amount is sometimes as small as 4 bytes, but typically, for most machines which require 8 byte alignment for doubles, is 8 bytes.  So in this usual case, if you ask for 12 bytes you'll *actually* use up *24* bytes:  8 bytes of heap overhead and 12 bytes for your data, and that's only 20, so an additional 4 bytes just for alignment!

Comment: Thanks your fourth explanation makes sense that there's extra memory allocated by the heap. The overhead is not referring to the pointers, it specifies the 12 bytes as the Node itself which has both pointers. Another question I have is, how does the heap determine how much memory to allocate? Why is it 8 bytes instead of 4 or 12? Or is this a language implementation type of question?

Comment: It _might_ be language dependent.  It is more often implementation dependent.  Many architectures do not allow unaligned access - e.g., if you've got an 8-byte double (64 bit floating point) value then the address of that double _must_ be a multiple of 8 on these architectures.  Because of that, compilers make sure double fields are on 8 byte boundaries measured from the start an object and then depend on the heap (which might be a compiler run time thing, or might be an operating system thing) to always return memory that starts at an 8-byte boundary.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that a doubly linked list node is 12 bytes in memory with two pointers?

Yes, if the data is 4 bytes, and the code is compiled for 32bit and not 64bit, so 4 bytes per pointer.

> Also this book I'm reading talks about how theres 8 bytes of "overhead" for every 12 byte node, what does this refer to?

That *might* be referring to the 8 bytes used for the 2 pointers. But it *might* also refer to the memory manager's own overhead when allocating the 12 bytes. Memory managers usually have to allocate more bytes than requested so they can store tracking info used later when freeing the memory (class type for destructor calls, array element counts, etc).

Comment: "`malloc()`/`new` allocate more bytes than requested, because they have to track information that is used by `free()`/`delete`." - most often: yes.  Sometimes: no.  Depends, of course, on the implementation of the heap.  (Plus ... there's no C/C++ tag on this question ... so it might not be `malloc`/`new` at all!)

Comment: @davidbak perhaps. But realistically, how often are linked lists used in non-C/C++ languages?

Comment: LISP (and LISP derivatives)? Haskell (and other f.p. languages)? Assembly?

Comment: Sorry I am new to the topic, but I'm learning it through python which uses CPython as its interpreter if that clears up anything

Comment: Note that _in addition_ to the heap implementation overheads you've also got, in Python, language implementation overheads:  Each instance of anything you allocate has a header of 4 or 8 bytes (typically) which let Python know what class it is an instance of, etc. etc. etc.  This is true for most object-oriented languages and most interpretive ("scripting") languages (and also in C++ for instances of classes with virtual methods).  I'll update my answer shortly ...

Comment: @driftdrift for future reference, when you post a question, tag it with the language/compiler you are using

Comment: @davidbak ok so in comparison to an array, does the elements of an array have this overhead as well? or does the overhead exist for the definition of Array only?

Comment: @driftdrift - good question!  The _heap_ overhead is only for the entire array - and _only_ for each element if the element has alignment issues.  The _language_ overhead is once for the array, and once for each element.  But I'll update the answer shortly so I don't get tich-tiched for carrying on a conversation in the comments ...  (Also you should ask about arrays, or alignment in general, in a different question - after first searching to see if it's already been answered ...)